# how do i play beep sound from PowerBuilder app?

Tags: api, winapi, powerbuilder, beep

I need my PowerBuilder application to play beep sound for at least two seconds. 
Can this be done with Win API?

Comment: Look at the Win32 [`Beep()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx) function

Comment: i did not know there was a PowerBuilder function beep(). I think that will be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the PowerBuilder Help:

> Beep PowerScript function
>
> Causes the computer to beep up to 10 times.
>
> Syntax
>
> Beep ( n )
>
> n  The number of times you
>   want the computer to beep. If n is greater than 10, the computer beeps
>   10 times.
>
> Return Values
>
> Integer. Returns 1 if it succeeds and -1 if it fails. If n is null, Beep returns null. The return value usually is not used.
>
> Examples
>
> This statement causes the computer to beep five times:
>
> Beep(5)